# Do you decrement the counter in a for loop after removing ArrayList element?

Tags: java, arraylist

Do you decrement the counter variable in a for loop after removing an ArrayList element? If so, is this because the list shifts left? I have provided my code, which seems to work:

```
public void removeLine(String ln)
{
  //loop through lineList
  for (int i = 0; i < lineList.size(); i++)
  {
    //check if match is found
    if (lineList.get(i).equals(ln))
    {
      //remove element at i
      lineList.remove(i);

      //decrement i
      i--;
    } //end if
  } //end for
} //remove line
```

Comment: Why not call `lineList.remove(ln)`?

Comment: Normally I would. I was just trying to provide a quick example using a for loop. Since removing shifts the list left, would I decrement i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to decrement it, or it'll skip over the next entry.

Alternatively, I prefer to *not increment* if an item is removed.  Like this:

```
public void removeLine(String ln)
{
  //loop through lineList
  for (int i = 0; i < lineList.size(); /**/)
  {
    //check if match is found
    if (lineList.get(i).equals(ln))
    {
      //remove element at i
      lineList.remove(i);
      continue;
    }

    ++i;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterator like this.

```
public void removeLine(List<String> lineList, String ln) {
    for (Iterator<String> i = lineList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
        if (i.next().equals(ln))
            i.remove();
}
```